# How to fix The update_transaction method is not supported for route POST. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to edit and delete user transactions, but I am stuck with this error:

> The update_transaction method is not supported for route POST.
> Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

This is my `EditTransferController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\transfer;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EditTransferController extends Controller
{
   public function update_transaction(Request $request)
   {
      $id = $request->id;
      $transfer = Transfer::find($id);
      
      return view('Transfers_profile', ['transfer' => $transfer]);
   }

   public function delete_transaction(Request $request)
   {
      $transfer = $request->id;
      Transfer::find($transfer)->delete();
      return view('AllTransfers');
   }
}
```

And this is `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/update_transaction', function (Request $request) { 
  $transfer = Transfer::find($request->id);
  return view('update_transaction', ['transfer' => $transfer]);
})->name('update_transaction');

Route::PUT('/transaction_profile', [EditTransferController::class, 'update_transaction'])->name('post_transaction_profile');
 
Route::post('/transaction_delete', [EditTransferController::class, 'delete_transaction'])->name('delete_transaction_profile');
```

Comment: This is the web.php 


Route::get('/update_transaction', function (Request $request) {
    $transfer = Transfer::find($request->id);
    return view('update_transaction', ['transfer' => $transfer]);
})->name('update_transaction');

Route::PUT('/transaction_profile', [EditTransferController::class, 'update_transaction'])->name('post_transaction_profile');
Route::post('/transaction_delete', [EditTransferController::class, 'delete_transaction'])->name('delete_transaction_profile');







// End Of Edit Transaction History

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. There's an `Edit` button, use that next time. Also, your error is pretty self-explanitory; you can't perform a `POST` to `/update_transaction`, since you defined the route as `Route::get()`. Fix your usage. Also, `Route::get('/update_transaction', function () { ... });` is **NOT** using the `update_transaction` method of your Controller. That would be `Route::post('/update_transaction', [EditTransferController::class, 'update_transaction'])->name('update_transaction');`. Finally, method names as `camelCase`, `updateTransaction`, `deleteTransaction`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few issues with the code you've provided:

1. In the routes/web.php file, the update_transaction route is defined
   as a GET request, but the controller method that should handle the
   request is expecting a PUT request. To fix this, you should change
   the route definition to:

Route::get('/update_transaction/{id}', [EditTransferController::class, 'update_transaction'])->name('update_transaction');

2. In the EditTransferController, the update_transaction method expects
   the id to be passed in the request, but you are not passing it from
   the route. To fix this, you should pass the id when calling the
   route, like this:

return redirect()->route('update_transaction', ['id' => $id]);

3. The delete_transaction route is defined as a POST request, but the
   controller method that should handle the request is expecting a
   DELETE request. To fix this, you should change the route definition
   to:

Route::delete('/transaction_delete/{id}', [EditTransferController::class, 'delete_transaction'])->name('delete_transaction_profile');

4. In the EditTransferController, the delete_transaction method expects
   the id to be passed in the request, but you are not passing it from
   the route. To fix this, you should pass the id when calling the
   route, like this:

return redirect()->route('delete_transaction_profile', ['id' => $id]);

5. In the update_transaction method, you are using Transfer model but
   it is defined as transfer in the use statement. So you should change
   the Transfer to transfer
6. In the delete_transaction method, you are trying to delete a record
   by passing $request->id but it should be $request->transfer.

You should change the above mentioned issues in your code, it should work fine.